# Within the U.S. Grand Circle area, where is the number of daytime trail permits limited?

Tags: united-states, preparation, permits

Within the U.S. [Grand Circle region](http://www.grandcircle.org/) (very roughly Las Vegas NV /Provo UT/Aspen CO/Santa Fe NM/Phoenix AZ), for what trails are the number of permits issued limited considering day use only?

I am aware of the [Coyote Buttes area](http://www.blm.gov/az/st/en/arolrsmain/paria/coyote_buttes/permits.html) in [Vermillion Cliffs National Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermilion_Cliffs_National_Monument) near Page, Arizona (lottery-based for Coyote Buttes North including The Wave, and based on who applies first for Coyote Buttes South, but the [Paria Canyon](http://www.blm.gov/az/st/en/arolrsmain/paria/permits.html) in the same area has no daytime limit).  Are there other areas where the number of daytime permits is limited for day-time use?

For the scope of this question, I am *not* considering trails with a limited number of *overnight use* permits, nor am I considering trails that require a permit, but do not limit the total number issued.  I am also not considering trails where access is only permitted with a guide, such as Antelope Canyon or areas in Canyon de Chelly National Monument.

Comment: Apparently, some roads in Canyonlands have [limits for the number of cars and bicycles per day](http://www.nps.gov/cany/planyourvisit/dayusepermits.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Subway, Zion National Park

Within Zion National Park, for most of the year, day-use permits are required for [The Subway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subway_%28canyoneering%29) and Mystery Canyon.  They are awarded [by advance lottery](http://www.nps.gov/zion/planyourvisit/subwaypermits.htm), or by last-minute drawing 7–2 days in advance.  The lottery is not required during the low season (roughly November through March).

This applies either for the full canyoneering route, *or* for non-technical hiking up to the point where canyoneering skills and equipment are required.

[image: The Subway, Zion National Park]
Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Subway_P1010240_wiki.JPG), CC-BY-SA user “True God of War”

---

### Moon House, Bears Ears National Monument

Within Bears Ears National Monument, the [Moon House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_House) ruins are limited for day visits, with apparently up to 36 permits per day issued.  Permits are available [through BLM](https://www.blm.gov/programs/recreation/permits-and-passes/lotteries-and-permit-systems/utah/cedarmesa).

[image: Moon House]
Source: Matt Peeples via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Moon_House_masonry_and_jacal,_Utah.jpg) (originally on Flickr), CC BY-NC.